# latest supported extJS Version

Tags: javascript, calendar, ui

What is the latest version of exjs that is supported by Salesforce?

I use currently  ext2.2 in my VF page

Answer (score 2):

In general, a Visualforce page is your own private playground if you're starting completely from scratch and only using your own custom functionality, you can typically use whatever you want.

There are certain best practices to follow to avoid conflicts where another developer is using the same library, such as the [well known `jQuery.noConflict()` best practice](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page).

Different JS libraries handle this differently.

In addition to that, the Visualforce inline page editor can cause conflicts (first hand experience with that one), so I typically avoid it when going blazing my own trail with third party libraries. But if you're seeing weird inexplicable things in your page and using the inline editor. Turn it off and try again. Or just use the developer console which has its own respectable preview feature.

Apart from that, Salesforce does not expressly support any external JS libraries or versions apart from a blanket statement that we support them in general and a few items called out in the Visualforce guide [page on external JS libraries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_javascript_libraries.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=library%7CLibrary%7Clibraries%7CLibraries) (thank you Mast0r for the link in the comments below). I would caution anyone that in this instance "support" is a pretty lose definition...I suspect that the statement on that page is more to make it clear that Visualforce serves HTML/JS/CSS to the browser and should follow support of browsers used by the end users. In other words, if you try to load up the latest AngularJS library and your users are running IE 8, you may need to do some work as per the [documentation on browser support and AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

As to the specific question on ExtJS 2.2, according to the [VF docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_javascript_libraries.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=library%7CLibrary%7Clibraries%7CLibraries), as long as you're not using one of several complex VF components that use Chatter functionality, it seems you should be ship shape in Bristol fashion. (Although, ExtJS 2 is [8 years old](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/details)!!! If this were my project, I might look seriously at targeting this for a technical debt release and move to updated APIs. JS has moved on massively since then and you're likely to get significant boosts in features, performance, etc.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How does this not provide an answer @mast0r ?

Comment: I would expect at least a reference to any official information like sfdc documentation. Additionally the answer given is not completely correct. What says SFDC? [The use of third-party JavaScript libraries and frameworks is supported](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_javascript_libraries.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=library|Library|libraries|Libraries) Can you completely rely on this information? From my point of view this a typical comment...

Comment: Fair enough. I can add more color. and I'd not seen the link you reference mast0r.